# Prevent Flyway Maven Plugin from downloading old slf4j jars

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, flyway

When I run the flyway maven plugin it initially downloads the slf4j jars with a version of 1.5.6:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.5.6/slf4j-jdk14-1.5.6.pom
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.5.6/slf4j-jdk14-1.5.6.pom (2 KB at 21.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-parent/1.5.6/slf4j-parent-1.5.6.pom
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-parent/1.5.6/slf4j-parent-1.5.6.pom (8 KB at 154.7 KB/sec)
```

This plays havoc with my Spring web app as I'm using version 1.7.2 of slf4j there and it gets confused when I restart it.

How can I prevent this? I've tried adding exclusions to my pom.xml:

```
<groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.3</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
```

but this still happens.

UPDATE: what this is causing is the following error when I build with Intellij 12:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/tom/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea12/tomcat/Unnamed_incrowdnow/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-jdk14-1.5.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/tom/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea12/tomcat/Unnamed_incrowdnow/work/Catalina/localhost/_/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory]
SLF4J: The requested version 1.5.6 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6, 1.7]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
```

UPDATE: output of 
    mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.slf4j

```
[INFO] \- com.googlecode.flyway:flyway-maven-plugin:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO]    \- org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO]       +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav-jackrabbit:jar:1.0-beta-6:runtime
[INFO]       |  +- org.apache.jackrabbit:jackrabbit-webdav:jar:1.5.0:runtime
[INFO]       |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.3:runtime - omitted for conflict with 1.7.2)
[INFO]       |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:jar:1.5.3:runtime
[INFO]       |     \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.3:runtime - omitted for conflict with 1.7.2)
[INFO]       +- org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.5.6:runtime
[INFO]       |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:runtime - omitted for conflict with 1.7.2)
[INFO]       \- (org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.6:runtime - omitted for conflict with 1.7.2)
```

TIA,

Tom

Comment: Plugin always downloads defined dependencies. They are not included in runtime and compilation.

Comment: perhaps not, but they are confusing my Intellij when I try to run my app. If that's the problem, how can I solve it?

Comment: could you please explain how exactly IntelliJ gets confused? what exactly is happening?

Comment: Try to exclude `<artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>` as well, since that is the one being downloaded.

Comment: yegor256: info added in the question; Sergiu: that was an extract - other exclusions had no effect on the maven output.

Comment: Are you extending a parent which defines this plugin in it's `<pluginManagement/>` section? If so, add the exclusions there as well.

Comment: It is really problem. If in dependencies it library removed from public repositories you are not able to compile the project. You can exclude it, but maven always will try to download it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the Flyway Maven plugin 2.0.3, nor Flyway Core 2.0.3 depend on slf4j. Check your dependencies. The problem must be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: thanks for chiming in. Very strange that this should show up only now, but since I haven't used maven directly for a while it must be a previous dependency that uses slf4j - trying to find it now.

Comment: output of mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.slf4j added to question, would seem to suggest otherwise

Comment: It looks like you need to exclude org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar and org.slf4j:slf4j-nop from org.apache.maven:maven-core and org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav-jackrabbit

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and solved it by using flyway-core dependency instead of flyway-maven-plugin dependency.

Answer (score 0):

FLyway downloads slf4j dependencies, if your application uses 1.7.x or 1.6.x versions, then you will encounter this issue, since flyway downloads slf4j-nop of 1.5.3 version and slf4j-jdk14 of 1.5.6 version. In eclipse, you can see this under Dependency hierarchy of pom.xml

In order to get rid of this, add all the following exclusiions and you are done

```
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>    
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>                
        </exclusions>
```